# cannot enter shell commands using rse in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-rse

I also have the same problem.  I am able to enter commands in the prompt in the Remote Shell View but the commands are unresponsive after I press enter.  I have a connection to the localhost and am assuming I don't have to configure anything for the dos shell to work right away.  The dstore daemon is running and the dos prompt does come up in the RSE Shell View when I launch the shell but simple commands like "ls" and/or "pwd" do not cause a response in the Shell View. I am expecting it to operate as a normal dos shell would.  Have I left something out ?